# read and get specific int line of the text file into variable on python

Tags: python

```
a_file = open('file.txt')
string = 'a word'
flag = 0
index = 0
for line in a_file:
    index += 1
    if string in line:
      break
index -= 1

lines_to_read = [index]

for position, line in enumerate(a_file):
    if position in lines_to_read:
        file = line
print(line)
```

I found the line where 'a word' is located, and I want to get those line into a variable

but it only reads the first line of the text file

how can I fix it

Comment: what exactly is your expected output ? do you want the entire "line" as output when the word is found in a line or? can u give an input/output example? i guess you need to iterate through each line and look for the word, when its found return the line? or in your case create the variable in global scope, iterate then assign the line to the variable

Comment: https://pastebin.com/1hFZ0XWy
its example of the text file

I want to print 'its a word'

Comment: Assign `line` to a varable then.  For instance, `if string in line: var = line; break` (`var` needs to be a global variable). Why read the same file twice? You can do that in one loop.  Welcome to StackOverflow, BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply iterate through the lines, and assign the line to a previous created string variable, if the condition is met, that the string occurs in a line of the file:

```
a_file = open('file.txt')
string = 'a word'
res_line = ""

for line in a_file:
    if string in line:
        res_line = line

print(res_line)

a_file.close()
```

you could also create a list which contains every line in that the string occurs:

```
a_file = open('file.txt')
string = 'a word'

res = [line for line in a_file if string in line]
print(res)

a_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

@Maicon has it, though in python you don't even need the global variable, you can create and set `desired_line` in the `if` statement and its namespace will extend to the entire function containing the `if` statement:

```
a_file = open('file.txt')
string = 'a word'
for line in a_file:
    if string in line:
        desired_line = line
        break

print(desired_line)

a_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is check for string in the line. This will do for you.

```
a_file = open('all.txt')
string = 'a word'
flag = 0
index = 0
for position, line in enumerate(a_file): 
    if string in line: #=== if 'a word' in line
        file = line
        pos=position+1
        break
print(file,"Line Number: ",pos)
```

**However** if more number of the same words are there, you can use a `dict` to get the line numbers and the value.

```
a_file = open('all.txt')
string = 'f'
dictionary={}
flag = 0
index = 0

for position, line in enumerate(a_file): 
    if string in line:
        file = line
        pos=position
        dictionary.update({pos+1:[file.strip("\n").strip(),file.count(string)]})
if dictionary!={}:
    print("\n------- Statistics --------\n")
    print("Total Items found: ",len(dictionary),"\nTotal Occurences: ",sum([dictionary.get(x)[1] for x in dictionary]))) #=== Get the sum of all numbers

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        print("-------------------------")
        print("Line: "+value[0],"\nNumber of occurrences: ",value[1],"\nLine Number: ",key)
        
else:
    print("Oops. That word was no found. Check you word again.")
```